# Eclipse automatically imports superclass for a subclass statement

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gmf

I have a Parent class(from GMF to be specific) with static initializer method initDefaults

```
public Class Parent{

  public static initDefaults(){
   ...
  }
}
```

I have a custom child class that extends the Parent class

```
public Class CustomSubclass extends Parent{
  
  public CustomSubclass(){
   super();
   ..
  }

}
```

In my calling class I am calling `initDefaults` method with the CustomSubclass name i.e.,
`CustomSubclass.initDefaults()` but eclipse automatically corrects this and types `Parent.initDefaults()`.

```
public Class ExampleClass{

  public void initializer(){
    // CustomSubclass.initDefaults(); this is what I typed
    Parent.initDefaults(); // this is what eclipse corrected
    ...
  }
}
```

Both `ExampleClass` and `CustomSubclass` reside under same package while `Parent` is from GMF as dependency.

Why is this happening? I have other plugin project with the same setup and there this is not the case and the `CustomSubclass` name is retained as it is. But I did not implement the other plugin project.

Whenever I am typing the subclass name with superclass method, the superclass is automatically imported and eclipse corrects the subclass name with the superclass name.

Comment: Sure, your `ExampleClass` has no static `initDefaults()` method, so compilation would fail. There is no inheritance for static methods.

Comment: I have other project with the same setup explained. There 'CustomSubclass.initDefaults();' statement works and is not corrected to use Parent class(Parent.initDefaults();) but not with my case.

Comment: The compilation would not fail, but it's a code smell. Eclipse provides for this the warning/error _Indirect access to static member_ which is disabled by default and the clean-up (which also can be run as so-called _Save Action_) _Member Accesses > Static Access_ which is enabled by default. Project specific settings can override these defaults.

Comment: @GyroGearless The compilation would not fail (see my comment above).

Comment: @howlger You are right. It is the project specific settings for the **Save Action** configuration. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse provides for this **code smell** (the compilation would not fail, but it's harder to read, a bit slower and there is no real benefit since static methods cannot be overridden):

- the **warning/error *Indirect access to static member which*** is disabled by default and
- the **clean-up or/and save action *Member Accesses > Static Access*** which is enabled by default.

These defaults **can be overridden by** the following **project specific settings** (tick the *Enable project specific setting* checkbox):

- Warning/error: ***Project > Properties: Java Compiler > Errors/Warnings***
- Clean up: ***Project > Properties: Java Code Style > Clean Up***
- Save action: ***Project > Properties: Java Editor > Save Actions***